Keycloak redirect to client after user/owner authentication failing with 404 because 302 wrong redirect url
The setup works only if Keycloak(localhost:8700) and spring boot client(localhost:8180) are in same machine(localhost).
when keycloack(https://cloud.keycloak.com) is in cloud with iis reverse proxy and spring boot client(localhost:8180) then redirect is failing.
The resource owner/user On successful authentication, request is redirected to client application with the code thats getting 404. I think because of wrong redirect
the below is based on keycloak log
[org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-4) type="LOGIN", realmId="ceef9cf4-789b-4d9fe-a31e-0e0dfb557", realmName="Test", clientId="myClient", userId="ffd49a-e326-4291-925d-62b5150", sessionId="1ce35dd7ad-766b-45fe-b729-a5e1d0a2c80e", ipAddress="xx", auth_method="openid-connect", auth_type="code", response_type="code", redirect_uri="http://localhost:8180/login/oauth2/code/myClient", consent="no_consent_required", code_id="1cedd7dd-766b-45fe-b729-a5e1d0a2c80e", username="abc@app.com", response_mode="query", authSessionParentId="1ce357ad-766b-4544-b729-a5e1d0a2c80e", authSessionTabId="xwgdYs4faM"

Recalculated absoluteURI to https://cloud.keycloak.com/login/oauth2/code/myClient?state=Ceh-6ilLRdXDvCp78bH7guUSsZy_UJPl2CksgosTg0%3D&session_state=1ce357ad-766b-45fe-b729-a5e1d0d2c80e&code=b2e3da1e-b0ea-4244-a7f8-7764922b8da.1ce357ad-766b-45fe-b729-a5e1d0a2c80e.5007d078-3bfc-4b68-9aff-60b9fc71d8c3

The above should be like http://localhost:8180/login/oauth2/code/myClient? but some reason keycloak converting to https://cloud.keycloak.com/login/oauth2/code/myClient?

The URI for the callback with the authorization code is a parameter of the authorization request. This request, and its parameters, are built by the OAuth2 client (the Spring application with oauth2Login in your case), not by the authorization server (Keycloak in your case). So, the misconfiguration is in your Spring application, not in Keycloak.
The https://cloud.keycloak.com/login/oauth2/code/myClient URI looks very suspicious: this seems to be a URI for the callback endpoint on the OAuth2 client (to provide your Spring application with the authorization code so that it can get tokens from the authorization server). Again, this URI is provided by the client with the authorization request, and it should probably be https://localhost:8180/login/oauth2/code/myClient.
The Recalculated absoluteURI in the log you shared makes me think that the client provided just a path instead of an absolute URI. But as you don't share Spring configuration, application properties and client DEBUG logs, it's hard to figure out what happens...

if all of them are localhost its working perfectly. I am not changing any code i just change the urls issuer-uri and jwk-set-uri to point to cloud keycloak

I doubt that it's working on localhost if you're configuring the authorization code callback URI on Keycloak (port 8700) instead of the Spring app (port 8180). Also, when looking for a misconfiguration, you should check application properties too (not only Java code). See my updated answer. By the way, your question is missing a lot of information: you should edit it to add application properties, Java configuration, Maven or Gradle dependencies, and last debug logs for both the authorization server and the OAuth2 client.
